# Changing the name of a div tag, which has been dragged and dropped with a helper:"clone" on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, clone, helper

I hope this makes sense but here goes...
I have a `div` which is draggable and has a helper on it, now what I need to do is change the name of the `id` when it is dropped on the stage, at the moment it gets the `ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging` class and I can't seem to add an id to it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the stop function of draggable.

**JS:**

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
    stop: function() {
       $(this).attr('id','dragged');
    }
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="dragme" class="draggable">
    test
</div>
```

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d1m5n/H5Utr/

Comment: I actually realised what I was doing was a really bad idea, so I changed the div to be classes instead of id's and it worked great. But it was due to the information supplied, thanks for that :)

Comment: Good to hear :) Would you accept the answer if it was helpfull :)